# Parse JSON collection from Rails in Objective-C on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails, objective-c, json, ios

I'm using TouchJSON to parse the output of a JSON Rails API, but am having difficulties. The overall goal is to loop through the response, parse the JSON, create a `Round` instance for each JSON object, and stick those `Round` objects into an NSArray so I can load this into a `UITableView`. So if there's a more straight-forward way to do that than what I'm about to show (which currently is NOT working, btw) please let me know.

The Rails API is returning a collection that looks something like this:

```
[
  { 
    "round": { "course_title": "Title A", "result": "+8" }
  },
  { 
    "round": { "course_title": "Title B", "result": "+4" }
  },
  ...
]
```

I'm also using ASIHTTPRequest and I can successfully get the response using:

```
NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
```

But from there, I cannot seem to get anywhere. Here's more-or-less what TouchJSON suggests:

```
NSString *jsonString = [request responseString]; // [{"round":{...}}, ..., {"round:{...}}]
NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding];
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[CJSONDeserializer deserializer] deserializeAsDictionary:jsonData error:nil];

// then I do this...
NSLog(@"JSON: %@", dictionary); // JSON: null
```

I thought from there I would be able to loop through the dictionary and create the object mappings using my `Round` class. But maybe that's the wrong approach altogether.

My thoughts are that the JSON being returned from Rails is an array of JSON objects, so maybe that's why the JSON parser doesn't recognize it as valid JSON? From this, I have two questions:

1) Should TouchJSON be able to accept an array of JSON objects like what my API is returning?

2) Is it possible to cast the responseString to an NSArray so I can loop through each "round" and parse the JSON that way? If I remove the first and last characters from the response string (i.e. "[" and "]") the JSON parser will only grab the first "round" in the collection.

3) Am I going about this whole process correctly?

Any tips/advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: In addition to @schwa's remarks below, you don't need to convert the string to data. Just call `-responseData`, instead of `-responseString`, and pass it to the appropriate TouchJSON method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the right tools, this is WAY simpler than you're making it. I do this sort of thing all the time.

Use [Stig's JSON framework](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/), and import the NSString category that provides the `JSONValue` method.

Then inside your ASIHTTPRequest response handler code, go thusly:

```
NSMutableArray *roundlist = [NSMutableArray array];
NSArray *results = [[request responseString] JSONValue];
for (NSDictionary *item in results) {
    Round *myRound = [item objectForKey:@"round"];
    //don't actually do the above. Do whatever you do to instantiate a 'Round'.
    [roundlist addObject:myRound];
}
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

EDIT: Geezo. Objection noted re valueForKey: vs objectForKey:. I updated my code sample, and I think we all learned something here.

I also didn't mean any offense with the phrase "with the right tools". OP was looking to simplify his code, and the RIGHT TOOL for that is the library with the simplest interface. I have nothing against TouchJSON per se, but JSON Framework has the simpler interface.

Comment: For the record `-valueForKey:` is the Key-Value Coding method in `NSDictionary`. Unless one needs KVC, `-objectForKey:` is the canonical method to obtain an element in the dictionary.

Comment: Ah, cool - I suspected this was a very easy thing to do, but I'm pretty new to objective-c (if you couldn't tell!). I'll give the other JSON framework a try and mark your answer once I get it working. Thanks!

Comment: "With the right tools"? TouchJSON is in use by a vast number of projects with no issues.

Comment: I seriously hope you didn't get downvoted just for using `valueForKey:` in your example. That would be way beyond pedantic.

Comment: jlehr: valueForKey: isn't a substitute for objectForKey:. objectForKey doesn't impose restrictions on the key. valueForKey: in theory does. Only keys that area also valid KVO keys can be used for valueForKey.

Comment: @jlehr You may think it’s pedantic only, but `-valueForKey:`, being a KVC method, won’t work if the key happens to start with @.

Comment: I think a downvote is massive overkill, especially given the purpose of the example.

Answer (score 21):

TouchJSON presents three main ways to go from JSON to an Obj-C object. They are all present in the header for CJSONDeserializer which you're already using:

```
- (id)deserialize:(NSData *)inData error:(NSError **)outError;

- (id)deserializeAsDictionary:(NSData *)inData error:(NSError **)outError;
- (id)deserializeAsArray:(NSData *)inData error:(NSError **)outError;
```

The first one will return return whatever, either a dictionary, array, string or whatever the root type of the JSON is.

The other two expect a dictionary or an array and will complain (i.e. return nil and give you an NSError) if they don't get the right data.

Comment: I like how the author of the library the OP was trying to use gives the OP the answer and then that answer doesn't get accepted.

Comment: That's stackoverflow for you. More of a game than anything else sometimes.

Answer (score 5):

The `deserializeAsDictionary:error:` method of `CJSONDeserializer` relies on the `scanJSONDictionary:error:` method of `CJSONScanner`. This method expects the "dictionary" to be an object literal. Therefore, your data must start with a `{`. Since your data is an array, you would want to use the `deserializeAsArray:error:` method of `CJSONDeserializer`.

Answer (score 4):

Read the documentation carefully, your code is incorrect. It should look like this:

```
NSData *jsonData = [request responseData]
NSArray *rounds = [[CJSONDeserializer deserializer] deserialize:jsonData error:nil];

// then I do this...
NSLog(@"JSON: %@", rounds);
```

You could also have used:

```
NSArray *rounds = [[CJSONDeserializer deserializer] deserializeAsArray:jsonData error:nil];
```

However your absolute BIGGEST mistake was passing nil for error. You could have avoided going to stackoverflow at ALL if you had passed something in for NSError and then checked that.